# Jenkins user gets "Permission denied" at deploying

Tags: jenkins, deployment

Deploying a PDF documentation Jenkins executes a simple batch file:

```
@echo off
REM
REM Adapt the filepath as needed
REM
set PDF_OUTPUT_DIR="F:\svnWorkingCopy\kostra\trunk\DITA\__out_pdf"
set PDF_DEPLOY_DIR="\\FILE-SRV01\Austausch\Setup_Masterbuild\KOSTRA_AKVS\Deutsch\KostraAKVS"
del %PDF_DEPLOY_DIR%\KostraUserManual.pdf /F /Q
copy %PDF_OUTPUT_DIR%\kostra.pdf %PDF_DEPLOY_DIR%\KostraUserManual.pdf /Y
```

It quits with permission denied. End of console output (in German) is:

```
[kostra] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins1093559218605334188.bat

F:\svnWorkingCopy\kostra>F:\svnWorkingCopy\kostra\trunk\DITA\kostra-pdf-deploy.bat
Zugriff verweigert
        0 Datei(en) kopiert.
Build step 'Windows Batch-Datei ausführen' marked build as failure
Archiviere Artefakte
Discard old builds...
#111 is removed because old than numToKeep
Sending e-mails to: fjk@akgsoftware.de
Finished: FAILURE
```

The Jenkins user is the user logged on that machine (Win Server 2012 r2) and has all Jenkins rights.

If I open CMD and execute the batch file manually, everything goes OK. Any idea why Jenkins refuses to copy the file? Is there a way to get a more detailed error msg. from Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are running Jenkins on windows. First check that if the user that started Jenkins is allowed to write on your directory. If that is not the case restart Jenkins with a user allowed to write in that directory.

Comment: The Jenkins build consists of to batch files, one for generating the artifacts, one for deploy them. If I exute these 2 batches from the command line, the build is deployed correctly. I'm logged in with the same account Jenkins uses.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for my environment (Jenkins as Windows Service):

1. The default system user assigned to the Jenkins service must be changed to the logged on windows user.
2. Even after doing so Jenkins as a service doesn't know about mapped network drives, so you must change these to UNC paths if you have to deploy to a local network share.